# Do web browsers have Unicode character files in them or they inherit these from the operating system?

Tags: browser, fonts, operating-systems, unicode, standards

If we create at least one new character with at least one typography set we would have to include any character file and any font file, in the browser *file tree* and also declare these files in the browser source code.

As web browsers "automatically" recognize Unicode characters and their font sets I ask if web browsers have Unicode character files and their font files **in them** or do web browsers *inherit* these from an operating system?

Comment: What do you mean by "character file"?

Comment: @gronostaj Afile which contains how to data should be rendered".

Comment: That's a font file.

Comment: @gronostaj Oh, I was sure a font is a s butype of a character... Well than, I guess I should find out what is the default font for my Windows 10 installment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general browsers do not do character shaping
by themselves, and depend for that on the operating system and
its installed fonts. Character shaping is too vast a subject
for any browser to invest the required manpower.
The Unicode standard maintained by the Unicode Consortium defines
144,697 characters covering 159 modern and historic scripts, as well as symbols, emoji, and non-visual control and formatting codes.

Browsers avoid the limitations of legacy encodings,
because HTML is designed such that it is possible to represent characters
from the whole of Unicode inside an HTML document by using a
numeric character reference of the form `&#N;`.

Some web browsers, such as Firefox, Opera and Safari can display
multilingual web pages by intelligently choosing a font to display
each individual character on the page. They will this way correctly
display any mix of Unicode blocks, as long as appropriate fonts are
present in the operating system.

I have personally checked the installations of Chrome and Firefox
on a Windows 10 computer, and found no included fonts.
I only found for Firefox the font
[TwemojiMozilla.ttf](https://github.com/mozilla/twemoji-colr),
although even for that a
[recent discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1686274)
threw doubt on its necessity for modern operating systems.

References:

- Wikipedia
  [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)
- Wikipedia
  [Unicode and HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the two big browsers often take the "middle" road: they *do* use the same external library that the OS would use, but they bundle their own *copy* of that library.

For example, Chrome includes a *copy* of the HarfBuzz font shaping library, and a copy of the FreeType2 font rendering library, and a copy of the ICU locale data library. (However, Linux Chromium builds often specifically configure it to use the OS-provided versions.)

Fonts, however, are *not* included with the browser. They're always a shared OS resource. Browsers may load non-OS fonts over HTTP if the page's CSS stylesheet requests so, but they don't have any built in.

Modern Unicode-based fonts are addressed by the Unicode codepoint. There's no additional translation needed – the page already contains text stored as codepoints (encoded in UTF-8), and the font file directly maps those codepoints to glyphs.

Browsers may include character *map* files for conversion from old character sets (such as ISO-8859-X) to Unicode, though again this often takes the form of "bundling a copy of ICU" rather than outright browser-specific code or data. (I haven't checked what Mozilla does here, though – it *might* have some specific code.) Conversion between character sets could actually be done through OS code (e.g. libiconv), but browsers likely want something that doesn't vary from OS to OS.

Something that *is* browser-specific, though, is the charset *detection* code – both Chrome and Mozilla have code that tries to guess what charset is actually in use by old webpages that use one of the many old ISO8859 character sets and don't specify which exactly.

Separately from that, the browser *might* include its own UTF-8 decoder (this is not a "mapping", but only an algorithmic conversion), as it's a relatively simple operation, so e.g. the C++ runtime will likely have its own optimized version.